# plotly rangeslider how to restore the limit bar on the slider

Tags: javascript, plotly, rangeslider

I have a rangeslider with slided limits, I need to redraw the slider with
the grey part like this. [rangeslider example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be1yR.png)

If I save the range values from the layout and restore it, it affects the
xaxis range for both the top and bottom, so it is not right. Perhaps
something like limit-range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature that was recently added in the [v1.10.0](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/releases/tag/v1.10.0) release (specifically, [this PR](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/473).

If you'd like to set an initially selected range on a range-slider, you can use this syntax in your `layout` object:

```
{
  xaxis: {
    range: [20, 30] // this is the range the *selected area* of the slider spans
    rangeslider: {
      range: [0, 100] // this is the range the *entire* slider spans
    }
  }
}
```

The range slider will by default span the entire range of your data, however by specifying a `rangeslider.range`, you can constrain this span. We wanted to keep the interface familiar with a "regular" range, so the `xaxis.range` will still set the visible plot range and the slider will behave accordingly.

As an example, [this mock data](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/test/image/mocks/range_slider_initial_valid.json) creates [this image](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/test/image/baselines/range_slider_initial_valid.png) and there's a few other examples in those directories using range sliders as well.

Comment: I was able to setup the rangeslider with a limited range for xaxis and
axis.rangeslider.range when creating the plot with the Answer.

Now I want to reset the rangeslider with different subrange. Is

Plotly.relayout(plot,update)

Comment: the right command to use?  I tried update with a new xaxis structure, the.